# MongoDb MapReduce with comparsion of dates

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a map function in a mapreduce query where I try to compare a couple of dates.

Lets say that the documents contains a property 'Created' with type ISODate:

```
{
  Created: ISODate("2016-01-01T12:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

In my map/reduce method, I pass a date through the scope:

```
{
   start: ISODate("2015-01-01T12:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

and in my map method, I print out the following

```
function() {
   print(this.Created);
   print(start);
   print(this.Created > start);
}
```

I'll get the following output in my log:

```
2016-04-25T16:19:04.921+0200 I -        [conn129] ISODate("2016-01-01T12:00:00.000+0000")
2016-04-25T16:19:04.922+0200 I -        [conn129] Sat Jan 01 2015 13:00:00 GMT+0100 (Vest-Europa (normaltid))
2016-04-25T16:19:04.922+0200 I -        [conn129] false
```

What should I do to be able to compare the Created date and the start date?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Visual Studio played a trick on me.

The test data is drawn from a json file, and for some reason, Visual Studio chose to change some of the `ISODate("...")` values to `"ISODate(\"...\")"` strings.

It wasn't easy to spot, so I guess the lesson here is 'don't use visual studio to look at json files'...